# Как сменить текст на странице полученный из url?

Tags: php

В общем появилась проблема - необходимо чтобы текст на странице менялся в зависимости от `url`, т.е если в `Url` слово "кошка", то на странице появится слово "кошка".

Comment: Изучите метод GET

Comment: уточните какого вида должна быть ссылка `http://site.ru/кошка/` или допустимо `http://site.ru/index.php?var=кошка`

Answer (score 2):

Для работы с адресной строкой (параметрами, передаваемыми через неё) существует ассоциативный массив $_GET. В самом коде php вытягивайте параметр этого массива и работайте с ним где вам необходимо
Пример использования:
http://host.me/index.php?object=cat

```
<?php
   $obj = $_GET['object'];
   echo $obj;
?>
```